# What is the opposite of fromtimestamp()?

Tags: python, datetime, bytestream

I'm trying to figure out how to import a binary file into python, but it's a lot of guesswork and trial and error.
What I'd like to do in this case to is find where a specific date occurs in the bytestream, i.e:

```
import re
import datetime
import binascii
import time

with open('inputfile.nda', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

# This line needs fixing
i = int.oppositeof_fromtimestamp(2019, 10, 10, 14, 53, 57.000) # '2019/10/10 14:53:57.000' 


time_stamp = i.to_bytes(4, byteorder='little')

df = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(time_stamp, data)]

print(df)
```

Is there a function (or set of functions) that can convert a date into a bytestream?

Comment: Datetime's strftime should do the trick:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `datetime.timestamp()`:

```py
import datetime

ts = datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 10, 14, 53, 57)
unix_time = int(ts.timestamp())
unix_time_bytes = unix_time.to_bytes(4, byteorder='little')
print(ts, unix_time, unix_time_bytes)
```

outputs

```
2019-10-10 14:53:57 1570708437 b'\xd5\x1b\x9f]'
```

Then you'll probably want to use `data.index(unix_time_bytes)` to look for the string, not regexps.

Comment: Thank you, this works for the first part. Would you happen to know if there's a difference between 01/31/2020, 31/01/2020 and 31-01-2020 in a bytestream? data.index() returns an empty list with this method, and I noticed that the original program displays dates mm/dd/yyyy format, rather than dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: Oh, those strings will naturally have different representations if they're stored as strings in the file. You're going to have to look at the file in a hex editor or similar to figure things out...

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. It turns out the date and time was stored as integers rather than a timestamp, which I guess also explains why the software version I'm currently working with can't open files generated using the previous version of the same software (which does use timestamps).